# compare two files containing doubles

Tags: c++, c, bash, floating-point, diff

I want to check equality of two files containing `double` numbers.

I should consider near numbers equal e.g. differences of at most `0.0001`.

It's easy to write a tester for that with `C` but is there an easier way? e.g. bash commands?

Comment: How do the files look? Do they have the same structure?

Comment: Are the files just a big binary list of doubles?  Or are you really talking about an ASCII file full of floating point numbers?

Comment: @dirkgently: want the behaviour be like `diff` command; but numbers can differ at most `1e-4`

Comment: Bash does not provide operators for floating point manipulations. You can look up `bc` and it should be fairly easy to integrate it in a bash script.

Comment: @Benj: An ASCII file full of floating point numbers.

Comment: @phantasmagoria: If the files contain only numbers, it'll be easy. else input files line by line and compare them character by character else you meet a number.

Comment: @a-z Is there a guarantee that there'll be the same number of entries in each file?  I.e. might a diff program have to deal with the possibility that entries are offset?

Comment: If you have two tiny numbers, their difference may well be smaller than .0001, even though they should not be considered equal perhaps.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It depends on application, maybe it'll be good that the numbers' ratio be in [1-1e-4,1+1e-4]; but I need to check the difference.

Comment: @a-z In that case your problem is more difficult and can't be solved by dogbane's answer (which assumes a 1->1 equivalence of position in the file)

Comment: You said you wanted it like the `diff` command which compares corresponding lines, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Give us some sample input and output and show us how you would do it in C.

Comment: To avoid compare empty lines we can read the inputs line by line. To avoid consider differences in white-spaces we can use stringstream(read string by string), and compare strings character by character else you meet a number.

Comment: as long as each number is on its own line, you could use cut to truncate off after a certain decimal digit (or sed using backreferences for that matter)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way you can do it:

```
paste file1 file2  | awk '{d=$1-$2;if((d<0?-1*d:d)>0.0001) print $0 " " d }'
```

First use `paste` to print out corresponding lines. Then pass them to `awk` to subtract. Calculate the absolute difference and check if it is more than your tolerance of 0.00001. If so, print out both values and the difference.

Comment: This would be a good answer if the comparable values in the files were guaranteed to appear on the same lines in each file, apparently that's not the case.

Comment: It does not check the equality of strings.

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not provide operators for floating point manipulations. You can look up bc and it should be fairly easy to integrate it in a bash script.

See this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash) on Linux Journal. That should provide you with a starting point. It is upto you to work through the file structure.